# Sorting by Value of Object in Many to Many Field Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need some sorting help with django querysets that involve many to many relationships.

I'm making a language-based conversation app and I've just finished writing a query that returns a queryset named `possibleMatches` containing the users someone might want to chat with. However, now I want to sort those users by the `level` of a specific language they have in their `user languages` table. I believe the solution lies in using Django's annotate() function for sorting querysets, but I've been having trouble finding the exact syntax to do it. I've also tried using filtered relations, but when running it, I got an error saying that filtered relations don't support nested conditions.

Each user has an `id` and a list of `user languages` represented by a many to many field. Each user language corresponds to one `user`, one `language`, and one `level`. For clarity, here are my models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Language(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, choices=SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)

class UserLanguage(models.Model):

    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='languages', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    level = models.IntegerField(choices=LANGUAGE_PROFICIENCIES, null=False, blank=False)
```

Anyway, I want to sort the users in `possibleMatches` in ascending order based on their `level` of language `1`. This is the code and query I have so far:

```
sortingLanguage= Language.objects.get(id=1)
possibleMatches.annotate(language_1="languages__language__id=sortingLanguage.id").order_by(language_1.level)
```

But I keep getting syntax errors, and I'm not sure what the right combination of filter(), annotate(), When(), and Case() is in order to make it work (I think I'm getting the syntax confused with that of filtering over many to many relationships). Does anyone know what the right syntax for this would be? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `languages__language__id=sortingLanguage.id` does not make much sense either. Imagine that a `User` has no `sortingLanguage` as language, do you want to exclude it from the `possibleMatches`?

Comment: They will always have `sortingLanguage` as a language, I made sure of that based on the way I filter in order to obtain `possibleMatches`. But I would also be fine with a solution that simply puts everyone who doesn't have sortingLanguage at the bottom of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter the many-to-many relation, such that only the `UserLanguage` that refers to the `sortingLanguage` is retained, then you can order on the `level` of that language:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(
    languages__language=sortingLanguage
).order_by('languages__level')
```

If the id of the sorting language is known, one does not have to fetch that object into memory first, you can filter it directly by the id:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(
    languages__language_id=1
).order_by('languages__level')
```

you can use an aggregate to order by the largest of the *filtered* levels:

If the id of the sorting language is known, one does not have to fetch that object into memory first, you can filter it directly by the id:

```
from django.db.models import Max

CustomUser.objects.filter(
    languages__language_id=1
).annotate(
    highest_level=Max('languages__level')
).order_by('highest_level')
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that you could filter the many to many relationship in that way. However, now I'm getting a duplicate user when I run `possibleMatches.filter(languages__language_id=sortingLanguage.id).order_by('languages__level')`, even if I add `.distinct()` to the end. Do you know what might be happening? I will clarify and say that I had to call `distinct()` on `possibleMatches` before sorting in order to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Gomes: can the same `Language` occur *mutliple* times for the same user?

Comment: No, the a user has to have distinct `languages` in their `user language` list

Comment: @Gomes: what if you use `.distinct()` *after* the `.order_by(...)`?

Comment: Same result, I still have a duplicate

Comment: @Gomes: what if you use `Max` (or `Min`, see edited answer)?

Comment: HI @Willem, I figured it out. It turns out their WAS a duplicate language for the same user (none of REST methods allowed for it, but I remembered the user languages had been added by a fixture, which had a typo in it). Thank you for all your help, it now sorts correctly from highest proficiency to lowest proficiency with the following query: `possibleMatches.filter(languages__language_id=sortingLanguage.id).order_by('-languages__level')`. But what is the difference between using Max and Min vs. just filtering it?

Comment: @Gomes: if there are no duplicate languages, then it is not necessary, so then you can use `-languages__level` itself.